# Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus without scroling to the end

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText with some preinstalled text. When EditText was created, I want to select all text and the positioning at the beginning of the text. But `selectAll()` always transfers `scrollPosition` to the end.

```java
EditText edt;
edt.requestFocus();
edt.selectAll();
edt.scrollTo(0,0); //not scrolling
```

Comment: try to use edt.setSelection(0)

Comment: The position is 0, but there is no text selection

Comment: still no highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this example:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:minLines="3" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Clickhandle"
        android:text="Click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
       // editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true); --> Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus
    }

    public void Clickhandle(View view) {
        editText.requestFocus();
        editText.selectAll();
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                editText.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is always post() option, if there is no other variants I accept this answer